# Show that if $a$ is a positive integer and $a^{m} + 1$ is an odd prime, then $m = 2^{n}$ for some non-negative integer $n$

Tags: number-theory

Can someone please explain this proof in a more detailed way.

PROOF:

Suppose that $a^{m} + 1$ is an odd prime.

Recall that:
$a^{m} + 1 = (a^{k} + 1)(a^{k(l - 1)} - a^{k(l-2)} + ... - a^{k} + 1)$ if $m=kl$ and $l$ is odd

Since $k<m$, then $a^{k} + 1 < a^{m} + 1$. Since $a>0$, then $a^{k} + 1 > 1$.

This is a nontrivial factorization and hence a contradiction. Therefore, $m$ has no odd factors and is of the form $m=2^n$.

Comment: Which step (line) troubles you? The general idea is that any integer $m$ can be written as $m=l2^n$ for some odd $l$. The proof showed $l$ has to be $1$. In fact, the proof would be more clear if the author said something like: "Suppose $l>1$, then $k<m$,$\ldots$ ".

Comment: I don't understand the contradiction part. Where in the proof is it contradicting something?

Comment: Primes don't have nontrivial factorizations, that is the contradiction.  The proof unnecessarily is phrased as contradiction when it could be contraposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I'll rewrite the proof with more details:

Suppose $m$ has an odd factor $l$ that is greater than $1$. With $k=\frac{m}{l}$, we use the fact that $l$ is odd to write:
$$
a^{m} + 1 = (a^k)^l+1=(a^{k} + 1)(a^{k(l - 1)} - a^{k(l-2)} + ... - a^{k} + 1).\tag{*}
$$
If you doubt the above expression, you can multiply the rightmost expression out and simplify to see that the result is indeed $(a^k)^l+1$. Now, because $l>1$, we infer that $k$ is strictly less than $m$ so $2^k+1$ is strictly less than $2^m+1$. This, together with (*), means 
$$
(a^{k(l - 1)} - a^{k(l-2)} + ... - a^{k} + 1)>1.
$$
Next, $a^k+1>1$ because $a\neq 0$. So what has happened is that you have factored $a^{m}+1$ into a products of 2 factors, each of which is greater than $1$. This means $a^{m}+1$ cannot be prime.

The above contradiction implies that any odd factor of $m$ must not be greater than $1$. In other words, the only odd factor of $m$ is $1$ and so $m=2^n$ for some $n\geq 0$.